# Shell: Open a file, add a line in a particular position, and replace a particular line. Is it possible?

Tags: shell

Hey guys I dont know if this can be done with shell? There is a script with 200 lines and Im just interested in changing:

```
 ...
 161. subject = subject.force_encoding('binary')
 162. body = msg.force_encoding('binary')
 163. 
 164. smtp.send_mail(<<EOS, @from, @to.split(/,/))
 165. Date: #{Time::now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X")}
 ...
```

For:

```
 161. subject = subject.force_encoding('binary')
 162. body = msg.force_encoding('binary')
 163. converted_time = Time.now.utc
 164. smtp.send_mail(<<EOS, @from, @to.split(/,/))
 165. Date: #{converted_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X")}
 ....
```

Is that possible using shell? I know how to add content at the end or change the file with new content using > and >> but I dont know if modifying the file in this way is possible. If not, I'll just use a perl script i reckon.

(the numbers at the beginning of the code are not code, just for reference, its the number of the line)

Comment: You cannot do much with plain shell. Bear in mind that in `bash` you cannot even copy a file (well maybe it is possible with some magic, but no-one does it normally). You need to use `cp` which is part of GNU tool-set. It would probably be helpful if you specified system. Windows also has a shell.

Comment: I'm on Linux (CentOS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax to replace the whole content of line 165 with `<new content>`:

```
sed "165s/.*/<new content>/g" file
```

In your case, and if I see it properly, you want to add content to line 163 and replace the content in line 165. So this will make the trick:

```
$ line163='converted_time = Time.now.utc'
$ line165='Date: #{converted_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X")}'
$
$ sed -e "3s/.*/$line163/g" -e "5s/.*/$line165/g" file
subject = subject.force_encoding('binary')
body = msg.force_encoding('binary')
converted_time = Time.now.utc
smtp.send_mail(<<EOS, @from, @to.split(/,/))
Date: #{converted_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X")}
```

Note I used line 3 and 5 in my case. I store the text to be used in variables and then use the `sed "s/content/$variable/g"` expression. The `-e` is used to do more than one different `sed` actions at the same time.

To make the changes permanent, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i -e ... file
```

will update the `file` with the new content. It is good to create a backup before that, that can be easily done with:

```
sed -i.bak -e ... file
```

It will update `file` with new content and the backup file will be created with name `file.bak` (or whatever extension you give to `i`).

Comment: thanks! when I run this program the corrected script appears as a "cat" in my terminal screen but when I enter the script once more, the changes are gone...

Comment: Good point @adriancdperu, see my updated answer referring the `-i` option.